# ionic2 electron and local assets

Tags: ionic2, electron

I am using ionic 2 to create a desktop app. Everything works fine. I have an issue trying to access the resources from assets. For my assets I have :

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

Those errors concern, for example, url in css :

```
page-dashboard .main-back{
    background-image: url('/assets/img/sheepsatmyvatn.jpg');
}
```

I am not able to find a clear solution for this problem. Any clues?

Comment: have you tried `url(../assets/img/sheepsatmyvatn.jpg')` ? the main `build.js` sits in a folder on the same root level as the assets folder and so a reference should have to go one up to access the assets folder

Comment: That's it. It works ! Thanks. You can put it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `assets` folder sits on the same root level as the `build` folder. Therefore to access the assets ( which after the build will be from the `build/main.js` ) you need to go up a level.

```
page-dashboard .main-back{
   background-image: url('../assets/img/sheepsatmyvatn.jpg');
}
```